# How windows buildpacks uses windows features/services?

Tags: windows, cloud-foundry, buildpack

I just started with buildpacks, I'm focusing specifically on hwc-buildpacks.

I need to enable few windows features and start new services that are not enabled by default, I'm not sure where do I need to specify that, do I need to write a script so that it will be enabled every time the app gets pushed? If yes where or how should I call that script?

According to [doc](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/hwc#running-the-tests-windows-only), it says to enable features in Test Section, but where do I enable it on Diago Cell? or Diago cell already has all `WindowsOptionalFeature` enabled by default?

It may sound a stupid question but I have worked on docker and unknowing I'm trying to get those concepts in buildpacks.

Say I want to execute this powershell script: `Start-Process C:/SyncService/txregwebsvr.exe" '/i + /e + /w' -wait` how do I mentione in  `supply.go`

It would be great if anyone can explain how buildpacks uses windows cell resources.

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/understand-buildpacks.html and https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/custom.html#contract. That explains the structure of your buildpack. The docs are for Linux, so for Windows buildpacks, you need `.bat` files, like `detect.bat` but otherwise it's the same. See how HWC does it: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/hwc-buildpack/tree/master/bin. Here's another example: https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/web-config-transform-buildpack. Hope that helps!

Comment: As to what you can do in your buildpack scripts, you can do whatever you want that doesn't require administrator access. Your scripts are not run as the admin user. In addition, the buildpack runs in a staging container, and your app will run in a separate runtime container. It's an important distinction because the staging container goes away after the buildpack finishes running, and so does anything that is not moved into the droplet.

Comment: I'm writing extension buildpack where I need to run two `.exe` as service this is the PS command for one service e.g `Start-Process "C:/SyncService/txregwebsvr.exe" '/i + /e + /w' -wait`, recently I have discovered about GO svc package. So by using this package if I write `supply.go` will those services along with `DLLs` required by the service will get copied in the app container? Also, are all `WindowsOptionalFeature` enabled by default in Diago cell? I tried to ssh in container to see what features are enabled but it didn't show me as it needs admin access, how do I know what is enabled?

Comment: Additionally, I copied those `DLLs` and `.exe` in a web app folder and ssh into the container and then ran PS command as mentioned above, it didn't start the process, is it because it needs to start at the beginning at the stagging stage?

Comment: Your supply script would traditionally be responsible for installing any binaries or scripts that are required for the functionality you're adding. It would also be the time to write any profile.d scripts. These are scripts the buildpack can add to have programs execute in the runtime container. I suspect you'd want to have a profile.d script to run your PowerShell commands as you probably want those services run when your app runs, not for the short period of time where the buildpack runs.